# Error in termux when trying to install specific python version

Tags: python, termux

I tried installing python 3.10.6 on termux but it gives me this error

```
apt-get install python=3.10.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package python is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python-tkinter python-ensurepip-wheels

E: Version '3.10.6' for 'python' was not found
```

How can i install 3.10.6 version of python on termux?

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.10.6 is a very recent release of python and may not be available by default on the OS repositories.

If you’re using Ubuntu or similar and you want to use a more current Python, you may install using the deadsnakes PPA or install from source.

For the PPA approach, run the following commands first

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

You may find a good guide on google if you have a different OS